# How can I add iphone Xs max in xcode?

Tags: xcode

I am trying to add more other iPhone here such as iPhone Xs MAX, iPhone 12 and 13 etc. I can manage to do in simulator but i can't not do on my button left tap.
[image]

I did try to go to device tap but it only shows my only tester phone. I am running Xcode on the latest Version 14.2 (14C18), and my Macbook is on Monterey Version 12.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Since new generation of **Xcode** they cut a lot of iphones devices becauses they have similar screens and sizes

for example:

iphone 11 pro Max has the same size as Iphone Xs Max

you have here all the information about that  hope it helps you!

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/foundations/layout/